# Time Complexity: Nested 'if-then-else'

Tags: if-statement, time, big-o, complexity-theory

I've written a recursive program in **Scheme**, and I'm having trouble getting the time complexity of it. I believe it goes out to be O(log(n)), but I am definitely no expert on this time complexity. Can you help me try and work out the complexity of this?

Here's my pseudo-code:

```
function A {

for (int i = 0; i < length.list(); i++)
{
    if (list is null)
        output absolute value of result

    if (s2 < s1)
        recall function A, adding item to s2 value.
    else
        recall function A, adding item to s1 value.
}

}
```

Here's the actual code in Scheme:

```
(define min-split (lambda (L s1 s2 mini)
           (cond 

             ((null? L)
              (if (> 0 mini)

                  (min-split L s1 s2 (- mini (+ mini mini)))

                  mini
                  )
                mini
              )

             ((> s2 s1) 
                 (min-split (cdr L) (+ s1 (car L)) s2 (- (+ (car L) s1) s2)) 
                 )
             (else 
                 (min-split (cdr L) s1 (+ s2 (car L)) (- (+ (car L) s2) s1))
                      )
                  )
                )
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If-then-else statements are of constant order, O(1).**

It **doesn't matter** how many nested if-statements you have, because you will have coded a finite amount, which is always constant order.

I would need to see more code involving your recursive call to see what the time complexity of the algorithm is, but the if-statement is only useful in creating a base case. It doesn't in itself contribute to the complexity of your program in any meaningful way.

---

Take for example the following program:

```
int foo(List<Integer> bar) {
     if (bar.size() == 0)
          return -1;

     if (bar.size() > 0) {
         bar.remove();
         return foo(bar);
     }

     return bar.remove();
}
```

The runtime complexity of this recursive program is O(n) because, upon analyzing it, we can see that a recursive call is being made for each item in our List, bar.

So, the **worst-case is O(n)**, because foo will be called at most the number of times, n, as the size of the list. The best-case is O(1). The if statements have no bearing on the complexity in themselves. They only supply the base / recursive case.

Comment: Okay, so in my program, it would be O(n) as well, since it calls every item in the list once? But it will be called as many times as the number of items in the list, plus 1 for when the list is null. Is it still O(n)? I edited my post / code. @ryuu1987

Comment: I apologize but it's been a long time since I did any Lisp, or Lisp-derivative. But maybe this will help: Even if the function gets called n+1 times, you can generally round to the nearest polynomial (i.e. O(n)). With Big-O notation, you can just think about the highest polynomial and exclude any constants. E.g. if the run-time is 4n^2 + 3n + 5, then Big-O is O(n^2), because n^2 is the largest polynomial. A function is logarithmic if values of say, n, are repeatedly reduce by a factor of itself...

Comment: ...E.g. if the function continually divides n by 2 (like in merge sort), the runtime is log base2 of n which (through a more complicated/mathematical analysis) can be stated as just O(logn).